Time translation invariance of the two-point function
Please refer to this 2023 lecture note by Douglas Ross. In this note, they compute the generating functional for the correlators given by Eq (4.7) for a harmonic oscillator action.
$$\begin{aligned}
&\left\langle x_f, t_f \mid x_i, t_i\right\rangle_j=\exp \left\{\frac{i}{\hbar}\left(S_{c l}+\int_{t_i}^{t_f} j(t) x_{c l}(t)\right)\right\} \operatorname{det} J \\
& \prod_{n=1}^{\infty} \sqrt{\frac{-i 2 \pi}{\lambda_n}} \exp \left\{-\frac{i}{\hbar} \int_{t_i}^{t_f} d t d t^{\prime} j(t) \hat{\mathcal{O}}_{\left(t, t^{\prime}\right)}^{-1} j\left(t^{\prime}\right)\right\}.
\end{aligned}\tag{4.7}$$
Now, if I were to compute the two-point function using the generating functional using
$$ \frac{\delta^2}{\delta j(t_1)\delta j(t_2)}\left\langle x_f, t_f \mid x_i, t_i\right\rangle_j\bigg|_{j = 0} \sim  x_{cl}(t_1)x_{cl}(t_2)-\hat{\mathcal{O}}_{\left(t_1, t_2\right)}^{-1}.$$
This answer doesn't seem to have time translation invariance i.e. it is not a function of $t_1-t_2$. Can someone explain to me if this is expected or not? I thought that the Schwinger-Dyson equation implies that the two-point function should be time translation invariant. Did I make a mistake in the above functional derivative?

Your time runs from $t_i$ to $t_f$; it is only a finite interval.  There should not be any time translational symmetry.

@Vokaylop What if you took $t_i \to -\infty$ and $t_f \to \infty$. Then?

It still depends on your boundary conditions at $\pm\infty$.  Or equivalently, in terms of what you wrote down here, whether the classical solution $x_{cl}$ is time-independent.
